# Google Maps in Android query for the new feature "upcoming events" near location

Tags: android, json, google-maps, search

I am using Google Maps API v2 to display google map in my app.  Its working, its showing my current location.  I want to display the new upcoming events feature, when I click the upcoming events button, it should show the near by upcoming events. Please let me know what query should I use to fetch it.  Thanks.

Comment: Do upcoming events save in your calendar?

Comment: No, its the new Google maps feature, like nearby places, it will show nearby place's events.

Comment: Have you found any docs related to it?

Comment: @bjiang yes, I am using foursquare api to get the datas....https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/